# highcharts x-axis irregular date intervals issue

Tags: angular, highcharts, ionic3

I'm trying to show dates in X-axis. but it showing like this

[image]

My series date data is `{04/23/2017, 04/30/2017,05/07/2017,05/14/2017,05/21/2017,06/04/2017.}`

My X-axis configuration is:

```
 xAxis: {
    tickAmount: 5,
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%m/%d/%Y',
        week: '%m/%d/%Y',
        month: '%m/%d/%Y',
},},`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts date not showing correctly on x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312709/highcharts-date-not-showing-correctly-on-x-axis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `datetime` axes, the X value is the timestamp in milliseconds since 1970. You have to convert your dates before passing them to a series data. You can convert it like that:

```
new Date('04/23/2017').getTime(); // result 1492898400000 - correct timestamp
```

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.x

Comment: Thanks Chmiel. it's working. but small problem all dates are showing one day after like 4/24/2017, 5/1/2017, 5/8/2017, 5/15/2017 in x-axis.

Comment: and also not showing 5/21/2017,  instead showing 5/28/2017 which is not there only.

Comment: Could you reproduce it (jsfiddle)?

Comment: It happens because you've `time.useUTC = true` (default option). Change it to false and it should work as expected. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.useUTC, Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cm4azod0/

Comment: my highcharts version is 5.0.14. i tried using globe.useUTC = true. but it didn't work. in demo also it's not showing correct dates. they are showing one day off and we don't have 05/29/2017 instead we have 06/04/2017.

Comment: Could you reproduce it in jsfiddle?